# MYSQLDUMP - disconnecting from localhost

Tags: mysql

I have to export an entire table from a database. It's a bit heavy (more than 10Gb).

Here's the command I use :

```
mysqldump -u root --password=PASSWORD DATABASE TABLENAME | gzip > FILENAME.sql.gz
```

Mysql version is 5.1.53.
The export stops at around 1.6Gb, with the message:
"Disconnecting from localhost".

Is there a max_size parameter, or a time_out ?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Thereis a max_allowed_packet, and there is a max_file_size, you must check your conf files, what size has your drive ?